# Tooltip linebreak stops working when I mix html and erb

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, tooltip, erb, line-breaks

I'm trying to dynamically generate a tooltip. I have a variable `@x` which I want to print in the tooltip, but I also want a linebreak. If @x == 2, then I want the tooltip to print like this:

```
(2)
Comments
```

The line break works when I'm only printing straight html. But when I add `@x`, the line break stops working, and it all prints in one line. Here's the code I have:

```
<%= link_to "hover-me", "#", title:"(" + @x + ")&#13;Comments" %>
```

which prints this:

```
(2)&#13;Comments
```

Does anyone know why adding `@x` removes the line break, or how I can remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= link_to "hover-me", "#", title: "(#{@x})&#13;Comments".html_safe %>
```

The string needs to be marked as safe HTML, using `html_safe`. I also changed your string concatenation to use interpolation, which may be preferred.